# FilePond React Crop plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

I am trying to implement the plugins for the Filepond library for React.js using Firebase on the backend. The documentation is thin in regards to implementing the cropping plugin. All I want to do is force a 1:1 crop ratio on every image added as a profile picture, but with the current code, it is hanging at `Waiting for size - Loading...`

Mentioned in the docs [here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-transform/) there is a hint at using transform plugin in conjunction to get the crop functionality, but not sure how to use the `create()` function to get this.

Is there any examples of implementing the crop to work as I intend? Or can someone show me how they got it to work? Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";

// Filepond / Upload
import * as upload from "../../utils/upload";
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import FilePondPluginImageResize from "filepond-plugin-image-resize";
import FilePondPluginImageValidateSize from "filepond-plugin-image-validate-size";
import FilePondPluginFileValidateSize from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";
import FilePondPluginImageTransform from "filepond-plugin-image-transform";
import FilePondPluginImageEdit from "filepond-plugin-image-edit";
registerPlugin(
  FilePondPluginImageResize,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview,
  FilePondPluginImageValidateSize,
  FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
  FilePondPluginImageTransform,
  FilePondPluginImageEdit
);

export class Personal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.updateProfPicUrl = this.updateProfPicUrl.bind(this);

    this.user = this.props.user;
    this.files = [];
    this.pathToUrl = {};
    this.basePath = `/users/${this.props.user.id}/images/profPic`;
    this.process = upload.process(
      this.basePath,
      this.pond,
      this.pathToUrl,
      this.files
    );
    this.revert = upload.revert(this.pathToUrl, this.files);
  }


  updateProfPicUrl() {
    if (this.files > 0) {
      this.props.updateProfPicUrl(this.files, this.pathToUrl);
      this.props.handleCloseModal();
    } else {
      alert("Please choose a file from your computer to upload first!");
    }
    this.files = [];
    this.pathToUrl = {};
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FilePond
        ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
        files={this.files}
        allowMultiple={false}
        imageEditInstantEdit={true}
        imageCropAspectRatio={1}
        onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
            // Set current file objects to this.state
            this.files = fileItems.map(function(fileItem) {
            let file = fileItem;
            file.uuid = uuid().toString();
            return file;
            });
        }}
        server={{
            process: this.process,
            revert: this.revert
        }}
        />
        <button
        onClick={() => {
            this.props.updateProfPicUrl(
            this.files,
            this.pathToUrl
            );
        }}
        className="s-btn"
        >
        Update
        </button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the image edit plugin, that's only for use with image editors like [Doka.js](https://pqina.nl/doka/) This Codepen shows an example with square cropping, maybe it points you in the right direction. https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/EQOLYe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to revisit this, and I was able to easily do it. I did not need all the plugins, but just needed the ImageTransform and ImageCrop plugins. I just passed the properties:

```
allowImageCrop={true}
allowImageTransform={true}
imageCropAspectRatio={'1:1'}
```

to my `<FilePond />` component. And imported:

```
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from "react-filepond";
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css";
import FilePondPluginImageCrop from 'filepond-plugin-image-crop'; // Crops image
import FilePondPluginImageTransform from 'filepond-plugin-image-transform'; // Changes image to match crop
registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview, FilePondPluginImageCrop, FilePondPluginImageTransform);
```